# SSRS : Filter not working on grouped column

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have created an SSRS Report which is grouped on Date and Time column. Date as Parent Group and Time as Child Group. Also I have extracted date and time from a certain column in my select statement as follows :-

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DetectionTime,103) AS  Detection_Date,
CONVERT(TIME(0), DetectionTime) AS Detection_Time
```

Further I created parameter and found out unique values from the given fields using the following code from this link http://mohamedakb.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-get-list-distinct-values-from.html and followed steps as mentioned to remove duplicates from given parameter:-

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(parameter As Parameter) As String()

Dim items As Object() = parameter.Value
System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0

For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
Continue For
End If

items(k) = items(i)
k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)

Return unique
End Function
```

Now as I am trying to apply filter on the date column its not working like no output is being displayed. Also I tried to use other columns apart from grouping ones the filter value is getting applied for those columns but not for grouping columns.Is there any other way or am I missing something ?

Comment: Does you parameter draw its' values from a dataset?

Comment: @RossBush Yes I have one dummy parameter which draws value from dataset and another main parameter which filters the value using code mentioned above.

Comment: Has the date column that is being filtered been reformatted for display purposes? If that converts the date to a text value, there may be differences in either the conversion formatting, or the conversion date values. if `items(i).Equals(items(i - 1))` is comparing non-rounded times, you could easily have no items removed from the array. So, what is the data type of the elements of items()? Are the times in the items rounded?

Comment: @LaughingVergil orginal date column is also a text value. I am just using convert function to separate out date and time from this text value like 2017-07-11 07:59:40:935.

Comment: You say its ok, however, when you run 2017-07-11 through your CONVERT function the date value returned,11/07/2017, and does not match the format you indicated above.

Comment: @LaughingVergil  I solved it, I was missing IN operator while applying filter. I used like earlier which was not able to filter rows.Thanks!

Comment: @RossBush Solved.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had an issue where filters were not working.  I found that by adding the column that I was filtering by to the grouping resolved the issue.

EG: I was trying to filter so that only items that were HasElement = 'Y' were pulled into the result.  I had to add "HasElement" to the grouping.  Once I did this the filter worked properly.

In addition, when I attempted to "total" the filtered values in a column, the totals did not work.  I was totaling in a column each row.  To get the totals, I created a new column grouping that was grouped by "1" and by the hasElement column.  Now the totals can be calculated properly.

Here's an image that may explain it better.

[image]